# Nuget package extraction without build

Tags: c#, dll, nuget

I have my own Nuget package and I want to "extract" it (get the dll inside it) without building the project.

- Is it possible?
- Can I do it to a specific folder?
- If it is possible:
  can I do it on "Nuget restore", "Nuget installation", project reference (when adding the project with the Nuget as a reference to other project)?
- Is it possible to do a post-process such as writing the path of the extract dlls to a file?

Thanks.

Comment: A nuget is just a zip file with some metadata. You can use any zip tool to extract its contents.

Comment: I know I can unzip it 
but is there another solution? 
and the other questions "how to connect to the nuget install /restore process" to do the unzip at the end of it.

Comment: I think this depends on the nuget, because how the contents of a nuget are used depends on the build steps (either default behavior or specified by the nuget itself). Maybe you should explain why building is not an option for you.

Comment: It can be a solution to do "build" but it is "high cost" process. Can I trigger the build automatically after nuget installation/project reference/project opened?

Comment: I don't think there's an automation to this. But after installing a new nuget or changing a reference, a build will automatically take place when you run your program.

Comment: The question is really an installation issue.  if you publish an application and install the application on a deploy machine the installation updates on the deploy machine windows dlls to match build machine so code runs.  Once publish you can recompile code on build machine and then just copy to deploy machine (if new code doesn't affect the windows dlls).  The same philosophy applies if build and deploy already are the same.  Then no installation is required.